# how can one see content of registers with c++?

Tags: c++

Over using gdb, any one can see content of any registers ?

```
 ex:

     x/x $ebp + 0x4
     print $eax
```

I wonder, Can I do same thing by just with c++ ? If yes, how?

Comment: Nope. Not unless you use embedded assembly but that's non-standard.

Comment: Why would you want to fiddle with such very-low-level implementation details anyway?

Comment: @K-ballo: And on some platforms, impossible (e.g. MSVC++/X64).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ does not specify any particular machine architecture; therefore, it would not be able to do anything standard related to (machine specific) registers. You'll have to check your compiler's documentation to see if doing these kinds of things are supported.

Comment: In fact, the C++ (and C, and pretty much all other languages, for that matter) standard doesn't even care if there are things like registers. You can implement the language, for instance, through a stack-based virtual machine or on an (exotic and obscure, I'd guess) architecture without registers.

Comment: @delnan I wouldn't call that worse, I'd call that better.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: In a "rate this" sense, I completely agree. But for OP's question, it's arguably "worse". Edited anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only way you can do this is to use assembly language to access the registers - but that's non-portable.

There's a good thread on the subject here:

http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/626071-how-access-processor-registers

and I asked a question a while back about usage of assembly in C which would show you the basics (in the solutions) here:

[How does C code call assembly code (e.g. optimized strlen)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300160/how-does-c-code-call-assembly-code-e-g-optimized-strlen)

Comment: The compiler *may* provide intrinsics for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this with inline assembler if your compiler supports it. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Extended-Asm.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline-assembler along with the mov instruction, but every compiler has it's own syntax for this (and the asm syntax is not always the same as well).